# Julia: @sync not passing control to the rest of the Julia function

Tags: asynchronous, julia, task

I am trying to understand the usage of @sync and @async macros in Julia. I am trying to get this MWE to work and the program does not terminate. Any help is appreciated.

```
function process_node(nodes, id)
    @show id
    sleep(1.0)
    nodes[id] = true 
    return
end 

function main() 
    nodes = Dict( i => false for i in 1:10 )
    jobs = Channel{Int}(15)
    for i in 1:10 
        put!(jobs, i)
    end 
    @sync for id in jobs
        @async process_node(nodes, id)
    end 
    println("done")
end 


main()
```

The program never gets to the line `println("done")`. I do not know why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the goal of this code? Perhaps it would make sense to remove the `Channel` altogether and simply spawn all 10 jobs asynchronously?

Comment: The use case: The nodes will have additional information which will denote the order of processing. For instance, each node would have a level (0, 1, 2) associated with it. Nodes with level 0 should be processed first followed by 1 and then 2. I use a channel to continuously put node ids, if a node with level 2 is encountered before processing all nodes with level 1 or 0, then it will be pushed back to the channel. I am also looking at time-based implementation where the level ids will dynamically change in time.

Comment: One thing that is sort of not clear is how to wait on a task without using @sync. I am not clear as to how the program flow is. FYI, I have used Kotlin's coroutines extensively and am used to the ideas of co-routine contexts and scope; but these are not really present in the Julia Language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong about the use of `@sync` and `@async` in this example.

the loop `for id in jobs` never return because it blocks forever waiting endlessy for values no more inserted into the Channel.

Directly from the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/asynchronous-programming/#Communicating-with-Channels):

> The returned Channel can be used as an iterable object in a for loop, in which case the loop variable takes on all the produced > values. The loop is terminated when the channel is closed.

One solution is to signal the end of the streams of values with a special `Int` value, for example `-1` or if this is not possible with a `nothing` value, declaring `jobs` as `Channel{Union{Int, Nothing}}`.

```
function main() 
    nodes = Dict( i => false for i in 1:10 )
    jobs = Channel{Int}(15)
    for i in 1:10 
        put!(jobs, i)
    end 
    put!(jobs, -1)

    @sync for id in jobs
        if id == -1
            close(jobs)
        else
            @async process_node(nodes, id)
        end
        
    end
    
    println("done")
end
```

Comment: How to modify this code if I do not know the after what time exactly the jobs should close. You are using 2 seconds which is fine for this case. But what if process_node is a more complicated function.

Comment: One possible solution it is to use some special values/type to mark the end of valid values to be processed and close the channel, I will update my answer.